# RealPlayer Standard does not allow to position within a track

Tags: media-player, realplayer

I am listening to a preaching of one hour long, recorded in one large real player file. It works fine, but as it is very heavy stuff to keep up with, I at a certain point tried to just skip back a few minutes.

Trying several times, restarting and skipping forward too, I realized that I always get an error, after minutes of loading.

Is there anything that can be done? Is it my installation or do others have the same problems? Anything wrong with the recordings (happens to all files from this source) that should or could be changed (apart from using a more decent file format obviously)?

**Edit** Sadly enough I can't do anything about the format, as the video cannot be downloaded. All I know about the format: it is an .rm file served from a rtsp:// url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using another player and see if there's any difference in the results. For example [Videolan](http://www.videolan.org/).
Which format is the file in and how did you concatenate the preachings into one file?
For information: Not all videos support repositioning. This depends on the format and how the video was created.

Comment: If this is a streaming server, it's probably RealNetworks Helix Server. I've no experience with it, but in "http://www.it.iastate.edu/realserver/" it says "moving the Clip Position slider on RealPlayer will cause the file to stream data from its beginning to the player." So it might be that the problem is rather with the streaming server, rather than with the software on your computer. Try to get in touch with the administrator of the site (in the url) where the video is housed.